# Не отображается желаемый спец-символ (css)

Tags: css, html5, символы

Пожалуйста подскажите, почему не отображается необходимый мне символ: По идее должна появиться стрелка http://www.templatebest.ru/specsimvol.php "влево" (с двух сторон от слова Text)? По факту появляются иероглифы.

```css
  DIV:before,
  DIV:after {
    content: "\8592";
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div>Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Просто с кодом ошиблись - `\2190`

Comment: Скорее всего у вас не подключен нужный шрифт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы перепутали десятичное и шестнадцатеричное представление символа

> Unicode Character 'LEFTWARDS ARROW' (U+2190)
>
> HTML Entity (decimal) `&#8592;`
>
> HTML Entity (hex)     `&#x2190;`
>
> HTML Entity (named)   `&larr;`
>
> C/C++/Java source code    `\u2190`

```css
DIV:before,
DIV:after {
  content: "\2190";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Text</div>
</body>

</html>
```